# I get an ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms error when I use sqlldr

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I apologize for posting a question that seems to have been asked numerous times on the internet, but I can't quite fix it for some reason.

I was trying to populate some tables using Oracle's magical `sqldr` utility, but it throws an ORA-01775 error for some reason.

Everywhere I go on Google, people say something along the lines of: "Amateur, get your synonyms sorted out" (that was paraphrased) and that's nice and all, but I did not make any synonyms.

Here, the following does not work on my system:

```
SQLPLUS user/password
SQL>CREATE TABLE test (name varchar(10), id number);
SQL>exit
```

Then, I have a `.ctl` file with the following contents:

```
load data
    characterset utf16
    infile *
    append
    into table test
    (name,
     id
    )
    begindata
    "GURRR"  4567
```

Then I run this command:

```
sqlldr user@localhost/password control=/tmp/controlfiles/test.ctl
```

The result:

```
SQL*Loader-702: Internal error - ulndotvcol: OCIStmtExecute()
ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
```

Part of test.log:

```
Table TEST, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: APPEND

Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
NAME                                FIRST     2           CHARACTER            
ID                                   NEXT     2           CHARACTER            

SQL*Loader-702: Internal error - ulndotvcol: OCIStmtExecute()
ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
```

And, if I try to do a manual insert:

```
SQL> insert into test values ('aa', 56);
1 row created.
```

There is no problem.

So, yeah, I am stuck!

If it helps, I am using Oracle 11g XE on CentOS.

Thanks for the help guys, I appreciate it.

EDIT:

I kind of, sort of figured out part of the problem. The problem was that somewhere along the line, maybe during a failed load or something, Oracle had given itself corrupt views and synonyms.

The affected views were: `GV_$LOADISTAT`, `GV_$LOADPSTAT`, `V_$LOADISTAT` and `V_$LOADPSTAT`. I am not quite sure why the views got corrupt, but recompiling them resulted in `compiled with errors`errors. The synonyms used in the queries themselves were corrupt, namely the `gv$loadistat`, `gv$loadpstat`, `v$loadistat` and `v$loadpstat` synonyms.

I wasn't sure about why this was happening and I didn't quite understand anything. So, I decided to drop the synonyms and recreate them. Unfortunately, I couldn't recreate them, as the view they pointed to (there is a bit of weird recursion going on here...) was corrupt. These views were the aforementioned `GV_$LOADISTAT` and other views. In other words, the synonyms pointed to the views that used those synonyms. Talk about a looping chain.

So...I recreated the public synonyms but instead of specifying the view as `GV_$LOADISTAT`, I specified them as `sys.GV_$LOADISTAT`. e.g.

```
DROP PUBLIC synonym GV$LOADISTAT;
CREATE PUBLIC synonym GV$LOADISTAT for sys.GV_$LOADISTAT;
```

Then, I recreated the user views to point to those public synonyms.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "USER"."GV_$LOADISTAT" ("INST_ID", "OWNER", "TABNAME", "INDEXNAME", "SUBNAME", "MESSAGE_NUM", "MESSAGE")
 AS
 SELECT "INST_ID",
   "OWNER",
   "TABNAME",
   "INDEXNAME",
   "SUBNAME",
   "MESSAGE_NUM",
   "MESSAGE"
 FROM gv$loadistat;
```

That seemed to fix the views/synonyms. Yeah, it is a bit of a hack, but it somehow worked. Unfortunately, this was not enough to run SQL Loader. I got a `table or view does not exist` error.

I tried granting more permissions to my regular user, but it didn't work. So, I gave up and ran SQL Loader as sysdba. It worked! It is not a good thing to do, but it is a development only system made for testing purposes, so, I didn't care.

Comment: Do ANY synonyms (perhaps public) exist on the database?

Comment: I believe public synonyms exist, but none for that particular table.

Answer (score 1):

I could not repeat your looping synonym chain error, but it appears the control file needed a bit of work, at least for my environment.

I was able to get your example to work by modifying it thusly:

```
load data
infile *
append
into table test
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
(name,
 id
)
begindata
"GURRR",4567
```